# Google visualization api: Tootlip action(button) does not showing

Tags: ios, graph, google-visualization, linegraph

I am using google visualization graph api on Web.

I am trying to show button on tooltip and Hide tooltip when tap/click on anywhre on chart area.

Tootlip action(button on tooltip) does not display When I write following line

data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip', 'p': {'html': true}});

I already written the following lines to show button on tooltip.

```
chart.setAction({id: 'sample', text: 'Ver detalles', action: function() { selection = chart.getSelection(); var selectedRow = selection[0].row; window.location.href = "yourapp://"+selectedRow;}}); 

tooltip:{trigger: 'selection'}
```

Also I am trying to dismiss the tooltip on tap anywhere on graph area. How to do that?

I am using following code

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script><script type="text/javascript">
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart()
{
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Dates');
data.addColumn('number','Glucose');
data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip', 'p': {'html': true}});
data.addColumn('number','Glucose');
data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip', 'p': {'html': true}});
data.addColumn('number','Glucose');
data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip', 'p': {'html': true}});
data.addColumn('number','Glucose');
data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip', 'p': {'html': true}});
data.addColumn('number','Glucose');
data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip', 'p': {'html': true}});

data.addRows(
[
['02:31 p.m.',100.00,createCustomHTMLTooltipContent('21 ene - 02:31 p.m. | 100.00', 'Tttt'),null,'',100.00,createCustomHTMLTooltipContent('21 ene - 02:31 p.m. | 100.00', 'Tttt'),null,'',100.00,createCustomHTMLTooltipContent('21 ene - 02:31 p.m. | 100.00', 'Tttt')],['02:32 p.m.',110.00,createCustomHTMLTooltipContent('21 ene - 02:32 p.m. | 110.00', 'Hshu'),null,'',110.00,createCustomHTMLTooltipContent('21 ene - 02:32 p.m. | 110.00', 'Hshu'),null,'',110.00,createCustomHTMLTooltipContent('21 ene - 02:32 p.m. | 110.00', 'Hshu')],
['02:35 p.m.',1000.00,createCustomHTMLTooltipContent('21 ene - 02:35 p.m. | 1000.00', 'Byzui'),null,'',1000.00,createCustomHTMLTooltipContent('21 ene - 02:35 p.m. | 1000.00', 'Byzui'),null,'',1000.00,createCustomHTMLTooltipContent('21 ene - 02:35 p.m. | 1000.00', 'Byzui')],['05:55 p.m.',null,'',555.00,createCustomHTMLTooltipContent('21 ene - 05:55 p.m. | 555.00', 'New'),null,'',555.00,createCustomHTMLTooltipContent('21 ene - 05:55 p.m. | 555.00', 'New'),555.00,createCustomHTMLTooltipContent('21 ene - 05:55 p.m. | 555.00', 'New')]
]
);          

var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));                               

chart.setAction({id: 'sample', text: 'Ver detalles', action: function() { selection = chart.getSelection(); var selectedRow = selection[0].row; window.location.href = "yourapp://"+selectedRow;}}); 

chart.draw(data, 
{
width: 319, 
height: 140,
chartArea:{top:20,left:34,width: '85%',height: '70%'},     
legend: { position: 'bottom', alignment:'start'}, 
interpolateNulls:true,   
backgroundColor:'transparent',  
legend: {position: 'none'},  
hAxis: {textStyle: {color: '#343434',fontName: 'verdana',fontSize:6},showTextEvery:1, baselineColor:'transparent',gridlineColor: 'transparent',count:0,minTextSpacing:20},                                   

vAxis: {title:'Glucosa', textStyle: {color: '#343434',fontName: 'verdana',fontSize:6},baselineColor:'transparent',gridlineColor: 'transparent',count:0},                                                  
fontSize: 6,
lineWidth:3.0, 
tooltip:{textStyle:{color: '#343434', fontName:'verdana',fontSize: 10}, isHtml:'true', trigger: 'selection'},     

series: { 
0:{color: '#d57829', visibleInLegend: true, lineWidth: 0, pointSize: 4}, 
1:{color: '#047d94',lineWidth: 0,visibleInLegend: true,pointSize:4 },
2:{color: '#d57829', visibleInLegend: true, lineWidth: 0, pointSize:6}, 
3:{color: '#047d94',lineWidth: 0,visibleInLegend: true,pointSize:6}, 
4:{color: '#FFFFFF',visibleInLegend: true,pointSize:0}
}                     
}         
);                          
}

function createCustomHTMLTooltipContent(readingInfo, commentText) 
{                   
   return '<div style="padding:5px 5px 25px 5px;">' + readingInfo + '<br>' + commentText + '</div>';                            
}      

</script></head><body style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);">      
<div id="chart_div"></div>                                          
</head>                          
</html>
```

[image: Current output of above code.]

Current output of above code as displaying in the image.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You have wrong tag at the end of file `</head>` instead of `</body>`.

Comment: @AntoJurković, Do you have any solution, let me know.

Comment: I didn't get it running. I noticed two `legend` options and I don't understand why is there so many tooltips column.